# Why utf-8 encoded byte \xbd is formatted to unicode code point fffd in a for range loop?

Tags: string, go, unicode, utf-8

This is an exercise from the [Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/strings).

`[Exercise: Put an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence into the string. (How?) What happens to the iterations of the loop?]`

And what I did is

```
    const nihongo = "\xbd日本語\xbd"
    for index, runeValue := range nihongo {
        fmt.Printf("%x, %d\n", runeValue, index)
    }
```

And the output is

```
fffd, 0
65e5, 1
672c, 4
8a9e, 7
fffd, 10
```

My questions is. How the utf-8 encoded byte `bd` is formatted as unit code point `u+fffd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is specified by [Spec: For statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> **For statements with range clause**
>
> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second value, of type `rune`, will be the value of the corresponding code point. **If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the second value will be `0xFFFD`, the Unicode replacement character**, and the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

Comment: Oh, so the invalid utf-8 sequence is replaced by `FFFD`, and width is kept as 1. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Spybdai That's right. `string`s are supposed to be valid UTF-8 encoded sequences, but if they aren't, this is how it is dealt with.

Comment: Hi @icza, thanks for the explain. Yes. strings literals without escape sequences should all valid UTF-8 encoded sequences.